# Graph explorer callrecords "could not find the requested call record"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to get call records from MS Teams and store it in another database and I'm calling callRecord to do that. I am running a python script on a console app and used these steps: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/console-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-python).

I have created a subscription in the function app in the portal, and I'm able to grab the ID from there through an HTTP trigger. The app information is stored in a JSON file, as seen below and that's what I'm running through the script.

{
"authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx",
"client_id": "xx",
"scope": [ "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" ],
"secret": "xx",
"endpoint": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/ID(from subscription)
}

When I run the script, I get this:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2fhS.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you want to view your call histories that older than 30 days, you need to contact the Office 365 admins in your organization and run either of the 2 reports below:
1. The first one is Usage reports. The admins can go to Teams admin center -> Analytics & reports -> Usage reports and run the reports for the last 90 days.
2. The second one is Office 365 eDiscovery, which returns items from chats, meetings, and calls in Microsoft Teams. Then you can document the time spent on calls.

Comment: Ref: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/older-call-history-in-teams/8e06e22a-2199-4c09-a5d7-5805c266edd1

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response and sorry for the late reply! The issue is that these call records are not older than 30 days. I'm putting in ID's from calls that have happened in the last week and I'm still getting this error. What can I do about that? Thank you

Comment: Could you please make sure if you are using correct id of a callRecord ? Is it working if you run the query via Postman/Graph Explorer? Also please try to query using the callChainId property of a [call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/call?view=graph-rest-1.0).